# mongodb (java) including id field by name

Tags: java, mongodb, grouping, projection

I'm following the mongo db aggregation in java, and the example shows the pipeline below. What I'm trying to do is add an additional field named `department` that contains the department value (so in this case it would have the same value is the `_id` field. I tried adding another field in the `groupFields` with `new BasicDBObject("department",$department)`, but that didn't work.

```
// create our pipeline operations, first with the $match
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("type", "airfare") );

// build the $projection operation
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("department", 1);
fields.put("amount", 1);
fields.put("_id", 0);
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields );

// Now the $group operation
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$department");
groupFields.put("average", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$amount"));
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);

// run aggregation
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate( match, project, group );
```

With an output of

```
{"_id" : "Human Resources" , "average" : 74.91735537190083} , 
{"_id" : "Sales" , "average" : 72.30275229357798} ,
{"_id" : "Engineering" , "average" : 74.1}
```

Comment: Hi, this post was very useful, I am bit desperate to understand how to parse the output results? In this case how did you cast the result into a POJO? If I use a while( ...iterator.hasnext()) it enter an endless loop ...

Comment: Why don't you post your code in a different question and we can help find the issue

Comment: Luckily I solved the problem with a 'for each' loop ('while' has some problem), many thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to switch the order:

```
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate( match, group, project);
```

Or you can add another project after group. If you are using `$project` before `$group`, it just passes values into group operator, not directly to output.

Comment: In the original case, it doesn't even look like the project before is doing anything

Comment: The projection works, but I have a case where my _id field is actually a composite id `_id:{a:"v1",b:"v2"}`, and I would like to have `a` and `b` as separate fields in the output, rather than grouped as _id. Is it possible to unroll the id field like that?

Comment: nevermind, I have it figured out. doing the projection afterwards is the right way.